# ctypedef in Cython with numpy: what is right convention?

Tags: python, c, numpy, cython

In Cython when using numpy, what is the point of writing:

```
cimport numpy as np
import numpy as np
ctypedef np.int_t DTYPE_t
```

and then using `DTYPE_t` everywhere instead of just using `np.int_t`? Does the `ctypedef` actually do anything differently in the resulting code here?

Comment: Does not matter i think, but it makes it easier to change it to another type later.

Comment: He's right. It can also be a little cumbersome to write things like `unsigned long long` everywhere. That's just my opinion though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the notes from the [docs for cython](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/numpy.html), reading the notes they explain the reason for the use of this notation and imports.

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
# "cimport" is used to import special compile-time information
# about the numpy module (this is stored in a file numpy.pxd which is
# currently part of the Cython distribution).
cimport numpy as np
# We now need to fix a datatype for our arrays. I've used the variable
# DTYPE for this, which is assigned to the usual NumPy runtime
# type info object.
DTYPE = np.int
# "ctypedef" assigns a corresponding compile-time type to DTYPE_t. For
# every type in the numpy module there's a corresponding compile-time
# type with a _t-suffix.
ctypedef np.int_t DTYPE_t
# "def" can type its arguments but not have a return type. The type of the
# arguments for a "def" function is checked at run-time when entering the
# function.
#
# The arrays f, g and h is typed as "np.ndarray" instances. The only effect
# this has is to a) insert checks that the function arguments really are
# NumPy arrays, and b) make some attribute access like f.shape[0] much
# more efficient. (In this example this doesn't matter though.)
```

Comment: Suppose I have pxd and pyx file, they all use function argument like this : np.ndarray[DTYPE_double_t, ndim=1] weight, but ctypedef in both file(pyx and pxd) will occur: 'DTYPE_int_t' redeclared