# Importing numeric C typedef into Cython automatically

Tags: cython, typedef

Say you have a `config.h"` header defining a numeric type with `typedef` as

```cpp
//config.h
typedef int32_t DTYPE_t;
```

or alternatively via a `#define` clause such as:

```cpp
//config.h
#define int32_t DTYPE_t
```

You could manually replicate (e.g. following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22083660)) the data type in cython with `ctypedef`:

```
# my_cython_lib.pyx
from libc.stdint cimport int32_t
ctypedef int32_t DTYPE_t

DTYPE_t a = 1
```

However, in the event of switching `DTYPE_t` to `int64_t`, you would have to do so manually. How can you import `DTYPE_t` (from a C-level `#define` or `typedef`) in the Cython space **without explicitly declaring the data type/size?**  I would expect it to be something inside a `cdef extern from` block, e.g.,

```py
cdef extern from "config.h":
    ctypedef DTYPE_t dtype_t # Error: DTYPE_t not defined

# This definition is outside of the `cdef extern from` block
dtype_t a = 1
```

Comment: If it's defined in a cdef extern block, it usually doesn't really matter what the type you tell Cython is provided it's still an integer type. The generated code uses the typedef from C anyway

Comment: @DavidW does the type need to be the same size? If I declare `ctypedef int DTYPE_t` inside the `cdef extern from` block and then set `typedef DTYPE int8_t` in the `.h` file, doesn't it release dragons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare the type in a `cdef extern` block then it doesn't really matter if the type doesn't match the C type. E.g.:

```
cdef extern from "config.h":
    ctypedef int32_t DTYPE_t # should work fine even if DTYPE_t is actually
                             # int8_t, int16_t, or int64_t
```

Practically the C code that Cython generates will just use the name of the C type (`DTYPE_t`) anyway, so all that's really important is that Cython knows it's an integer type.

Anywhere that Cython needs to know the size of the type (largely for detecting overflows) it works this out in the generated C code anyway, so doesn't need to know itself.

This is a fairly common way of handling platform depending types in Cython so is nothing to worry about.